# JavaScript ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code was showing an ajax updated sql table. The page now loads to a blank table with header rows showing. I'm having a difficult time seeing why this won't render the table. No error is thrown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script>
            setInterval(function() {
                refreshTable();
            }, sleepTime);

            /*creates function refreshTable which uses javascript to post data to sqlAjax.php*/
            function refreshTable() {
                sleepTime = 5000;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "sqlAjax.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data); // "something"
                        updateTable(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            /*creates function updateTable that appends the body of the table*/
            function updateTable(tableData) {
                $("#priceTable tbody tr").empty();
                var $tr = $(tableData);
                $('#priceTable > tbody:first').append($tr);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width:80%;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            th {
                background:#95bce2;
                color:white;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            td, th {
                padding:6px;
                border:1px solid #95bce2;
                text-align:left;
            }
            .even {
                background-color:#ecf6fc;
            }
            .odd {
                background-color:white;
            }
            .hover {
                background-color:#ccc!important;
            }
            .focus {
                background-color:#6ab9d0!important;
                color:white;
            }
            â
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div span class="span4">
            <table id='priceTable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Order ID</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>DID</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `sleepTime` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the sleepTime declaration a global variable so that it would be seen by all function

> var sleepTime = 5000;
>
> setInterval(function() {
>                   refreshTable();
>               }, sleepTime);

Answer (score 0):

Why do yuo need setTimeout? To run your code when page is loaded? If so you should use `$(document).ready(function() { ... code here ... });` approach.

Comment: you have a point. one could use the ready function of jquery instead